# Can this topic be migrated to World Builder

Tags: discussion

Since worldbuilder recently graduated and is now eligible for migration, can [this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9580/what-would-happen-if-i-tried-to-buy-the-entire-russian-stock-market) be migrated, or would I be better off just asking the question as a new question over there?

Comment: I sent the question over to world building. Hope you get some help there,